# Como Criar e ler arquivos ".conf" em C, para ambiente linux?

Tags: c, configuração

Estou estudando C em ambiente linux.

Estou com um problema em como criar um arquivo de configuração para meu programa saber o que deve fazer ao ser executado.

#### Questão

- Alguém sabe como armazenar e ler variáveis em arquivos `.conf`?
- Existe uma técnica pra isso?
- Qual o padrão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Lib confuse, esta tudo pronto... eh simplesmente magico... 
eis o link original da materia:
https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Criando-programas-com-suporte-a-arquivos-de-configuracao-com-a-libConfuse?pagina=5

pode baixar direto do link deles:

```
http://savannah.nongnu.org/download/confuse/
```

instalar eu facil:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ su -c 'make install'
```

se nao estiver no dir /usr/include, copie:

```
$ cd src/
$ su -c 'cp confuse.h /usr/include'
```

Olha um exemplo de uso que esta no proprio artigo:

```
int main(void)
{
   int porta;
   char *servidor = NULL;
   cfg_t *cfg;
   cfg_opt_t opts[] = {
             CFG_SIMPLE_STR ("server", &servidor),
             CFG_SIMPLE_INT ("port", &porta),
             CFG_END()
             };
   cfg = cfg_init (opts, 0);
   cfg_parse (cfg, "exemplo.conf");

   printf ("\nServidor: %s \n", servidor);
   printf ("Porta: %d \n", porta);
   cfg_free(cfg);       /* Libera a memória alocada por cfg_init */
   return 0;
}
```

exemplo do arquivo de .config = exemplo.conf

```
 # Arquivo de configuração para teste.

server = "www.kernel.org"
port = 80

# Fim do arquivo de configuração.
```

Comment: Realmente, preciso de agilidade....  isso esta todo pronto....

Comment: Que engracado!  depois do seu post, outros amigos mudaram um pouco os posts deles!   Tipo, retiraram a parte "temque fazer tudo na mao, e vai dar trabalho..."   para .. "Ta chei de opcoes por ai!!!  "   sera que a turma que le os posts... tambem... da uma lida nas edicoes_????  antes de dar positivo pra galeta?

Answer (score 13):

A extensão de um [arquivo de configuração](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file) não se limita somente à `.conf`, também pode ser `.cnf`, `.conf`, `.cfg`, ou [`.ini`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file) por exemplo. Não há um padrão de como um arquivo de configuração pode ser chamado.

É possível fazer a leitura manualmente, porém é uma tarefa um tanto trabalhosa, você pode usar o [`fopen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) para abrir o arquivo para leitura, [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) para ler linha por linha, e o [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/) para analisar a linha e obter os valores.

Essa abordagem pode ser um pouco limitada, talvez funcione em certas situações onde você conhece a estrutura do arquivo, porém pode deixar de funcionar se tiver um espaço ou linha a mais. [**Veja aqui uma implementação**](ftp://ftp.lanl.gov/public/rothrock/NPOD-E15P/jsr16_control/iniparser.c).

No Windows é possível usar as APIs [`GetPrivateProfileString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353.aspx) para retornar um valor, [`GetPrivateProfileInt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724345.aspx) para retornar um inteiro e [`GetPrivateProfileSection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724348(v=vs.85).aspx) para retornar as chaves e valores de uma seção.

Para [**Qt**](https://www.qt.io/) é possível usar as funções da classe [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html).

Não há uma opção nativa para fazer a leitura de um arquivo de configuração, porém existem alternativas como:

- [**Libconfig**](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/): C/C++. Disponível para GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, Solaris, FreeBSD, Android, e Windows. [**Documentação**](http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/libconfig_manual.html).
- [**LibIni**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libini/): C, C++, Visual Basic, Java, TCL, Perl, Python. Disponível para Windows, DOS, GNU/Linux.
- [**libConfuse**](https://github.com/martinh/libconfuse): C. Assim como os outros acima, também está disponível para Windows e sistemas baseados no Unix. [**Tutorial**](http://www.nongnu.org/confuse/tutorial-html/).
- [**inih**](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih): C/C++. Foi projetado para ser leve e simples, o desenvolvedor desse projeto parece ter dado prioridade à isso para ser compatível com sistemas embarcados.
- Entre outros...

Para criar um exemplo vou usar o **inih**, o código é uma adaptação desse [**exemplo da documentação**](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih#simple-example-in-c).

1. Supondo que você tenha um arquivo de configuração `foo.cfg` como abaixo:

   ```
   ; Exemplo de arquivo de configuração

   [usuario]
   nome = João Silva ; Os espaços entre "=" são removidos
   peso = 90.5       ; Valor de ponto flutuante
   idade = 100       ; Valor inteiro
   ativo = true      ; Valor booleano

   [local]
   cidade = Rio Branco ; Os comentários serão ignorados (como esse)
   estado = Acre
   ```
2. Para guardar as informações que serão lidas do arquivo, usaremos a estrutura abaixo:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       const char* nome;
       float peso;
       int idade;
       bool ativo;

       const char* cidade;
       const char* estado;
   } configuracao;
   ```
3. Como mencionado na [documentação](https://github.com/benhoyt/inih#simple-example-in-c), use um *handler* para identificar a seção e chave e guardar o valor na estrutura. O *handler/callback* é chamado toda vez que um par de `chave=valor` é analisado. Nesse exemplo, podemos fazer assim:

   ```
   static int handler(void* usuario, const char* secao, const char* nome, const char* valor)
   {
       configuracao* cfg = (configuracao*)usuario;
       #define MATCH(s, n) strcmp(secao, s) == 0 && strcmp(nome, n) == 0

       /* Identifica a seção e chave e guarda seu valor na estrutura */

       if (MATCH("usuario", "nome")) {
           cfg->nome = strdup(valor);
       } else if (MATCH("usuario", "peso")) {
           cfg->peso = atof(valor);
       } else if (MATCH("usuario", "idade")) {
           cfg->idade = atoi(valor);
       } else if (MATCH("usuario", "ativo")) {
           cfg->ativo = (bool)valor;

       } else if (MATCH("local", "cidade")) {
           cfg->cidade = strdup(valor);
       } else if (MATCH("local", "estado")) {
           cfg->estado = strdup(valor);

       } else {
           return 0;  /* Seção desconhecida ou chave inválida */
       }
       return 1;
   }
   ```
4. Por fim, na função principal do programa, `main()`, você usa a função `ini_parse` para carregar o arquivo de configuração:

   ```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       configuracao cfg;

       if (ini_parse("foo.cfg", handler, &cfg) < 0) {
           printf("Não foi possível carregar 'foo.cfg'\n");
           return 1;
       }
       printf("Configurações carregadas do arquivo 'foo.cfg'\n");

       printf("Nome: %s\nPeso: %f\nIdade: %d\nAtivo: %d\n", cfg.nome, cfg.peso, 
                                                            cfg.idade, cfg.ativo);
       printf("Cidade: %s, Estado: %s\n", cfg.cidade, cfg.estado);

       return 0;
   }
   ```

O código completo fica assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include ".ini.h" /* Assumindo que o header esteja no mesmo diretório */

typedef struct {
    const char* nome;
    float peso;
    int idade;
    bool ativo;

    const char* cidade;
    const char* estado;
} configuracao;

static int handler(void* usuario, const char* secao, const char* nome, const char* valor) {
    configuracao* cfg = (configuracao*)usuario;
    #define MATCH(s, n) strcmp(secao, s) == 0 && strcmp(nome, n) == 0

    if (MATCH("usuario", "nome")) {
        cfg->nome = strdup(valor);
    } else if (MATCH("usuario", "peso")) {
        cfg->peso = atof(valor);
    } else if (MATCH("usuario", "idade")) {
        cfg->idade = atoi(valor);
    } else if (MATCH("usuario", "ativo")) {
        cfg->ativo = (bool)valor;

    } else if (MATCH("local", "cidade")) {
        cfg->cidade = strdup(valor);
    } else if (MATCH("local", "estado")) {
        cfg->estado = strdup(valor);
    } else {
        return 0;  /* Seção desconhecida ou chave inválida */
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    configuracao cfg;

    if (ini_parse("foo.cfg", handler, &cfg) < 0) {
        printf("Não foi possível carregar 'foo.cfg'\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Configurações carregadas do arquivo 'foo.cfg'\n");

    printf("Nome: %s\nPeso: %f\nIdade: %d\nAtivo: %d\n", cfg.nome, cfg.peso, 
                                                         cfg.idade, cfg.ativo);
    printf("Cidade: %s, Estado: %s\n", cfg.cidade, cfg.estado);

    return 0;
}
```

Demonstração:

```
$ gcc -o bar main.c ini.c
$ ./bar
Configurações carregadas do arquivo 'foo.cfg'
Nome: João Silva
Peso: 90.500000
Idade: 100
Ativo: 1
Cidade: Rio Branco, Estado: Acre
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Existem diversas maneiras de criar arquivos de configuração. Os arquivos de configuração em `/etc` tem uma estrutura própria para o usuário ler.

Caso queira apenas armazenas os valores de suas variáveis nos arquivos, de modo que apenas o sistema leia, pode usar o `fwrite` e o `fread`.

Esse método é apenas para salvar informações do sistema, caso tente editar o arquivo na mão, pode dar algum erro e o sistema pode carregar as informações de modo errado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _config{
    char string[16];
    int number;
    float o_number;
    char name[32];
};

void write_config(const char *fd_conf, struct _config *cfg){
    FILE *f = fopen(fd_conf, "w");
    fwrite(cfg, sizeof(struct _config), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}

void read_config(const char *fd_conf, struct _config *cfg){
    FILE *f = fopen(fd_conf, "r");
    fread(cfg, sizeof(struct _config), 1, f);
    fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct _config conf = {0};
    conf.number = 10;
    conf.o_number = 3.7f;
    strcpy(conf.string, "texto");
    strcpy(conf.name, "I am a user!");

    write_config("file.cfg", &conf);

    struct _config conf2 = {0};
    read_config("file.cfg", &conf2);

    printf("%d|%f|%s|%s\n",conf2.number, conf2.o_number, conf.string, conf2.name);

    return 0;
}
```